# String de conexão SQL SERVER para asp clássico

Tags: sql-server, asp, conexão

Como crio uma string de conexão para o **ASP clássico** para se conectar com o banco de dados Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pegando da fonte, sempre que precisei utilizei essas connections strings, dependendo do seu SQL SERVER e dos providers instalados na maquina da aplicação, voce pode fazer uso de qualquer Native Client para se conectar a uma versão do SQL SERVER superior ou igual à versão do seu native client.

**Native Client**: O native client é uma blibioteca específica para otimizar a conexão com o SQL SERVER e permite trabalhar com a persistencia e captura de dados com todas as features que o SQL SERVER (da versão do native) permite (Ex: Tipos de dados e consultas novas etc...).

Fonte: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

```
Set oBanco = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

SQL SERVER 2012:

```
oBanco.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=IPSERVIDOR;Database=BASEDEDADOS;Uid=USUARIO;Pwd=SENHA;"
```

SQL SERVER 2008:

```
oBanco.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=IPSERVIDOR;Database=BASEDEDADOS;Uid=USUARIO;Pwd=SENHA;"
```

SQL SERVER 2005

```
oBanco.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=IPSERVIDOR;Database=BASEDEDADOS;Uid=USUARIO;Pwd=SENHA;"
```

SQL SERVER (**Todos com acesso não nativo**)

```
oBanco.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=IPSERVIDOR;Initial Catalog=BASEDEDADOS;User ID=USUARIO;Password=SENHA;"
```

Comment: Perfeito Roger. Utilizamos a string de conexão do SQL server 2012 utilizando o provider=SQLNCLI11; e funcionou perfeitamente com o Sql server 2017. Muito obrigado!